# Specify folder structure of dotnet core nuget package?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-standard-2.0

I have a solution with a dotnet core 2.2 app with projects having target framework netstandard2.0 using a nuget package with a flat folder structure:

```
packages
└── myPackage
    └── 0.5.0
        ├── myPackage.dll
        ├── myPackage.0.5.0.nupkg
        └── ...Some more nuget files
```

however when referencing that package, it doesn't work.
I've noticed other packages have a bit deeper folder structure and if i manually mimic that, the package works fine

```
packages
└── myPackage
    └── 0.5.0
        ├── myPackage.0.5.0.nupkg
        ├── ...Some more nuget files...
        └── lib
            └── netstandard2.0
                └── myPackage.dll
```

Is it possible to have some setting in the project using the nuget to understand the first folder structure? Or do I need to change the way the nuget is packaged to follow the deeper folder structure?
Is it something with the targetframework netstandard2.0?

the way it is referenced in the csproj right now is

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>    
<ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="myPackage" Version="0.5.0"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Did not solve my issue, but i resolved it by changing the way the package is packaged so that it follows the working folder structure

Comment: You can mark your own answer as accepted.